# Make Up-sell show only Saleable

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, upselling

How can I make up sell to show only saleable products? `if ($_product->isSaleable())` doesn't work in this case.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you load Upsell Collection it doesnt give you complete product data. So you must load product `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(ID)` and then check **IsSaleable()**

```
<?php 
     $object = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
     foreach($upsell_product as $_upsell):

        //get detail of single upsell product using upsell product id
        $upsp = $object->load($_upsell->getId());

        if($upsp->isSaleable()){
             echo "Product is Saleable: ". $upsp->getName();
        }


     endforeach;
 ?>
```

is this enough for you?? or you need more details??

Comment: Thank you. I believe it would be helpful if I didn't find extension iWeb Auto Related Products which has this function in it.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is filter **product collection  by salable using** below code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
```

if you get product collection  by `$product->getUpSellProductCollection()`.

Then you can filter collection by  Salable by below code:

```
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')
->addInStockFilterToCollection($product->getUpSellProductCollection())
```

If you default magento  `upsell.phtml` then you can filter then `collection using event /observer` because of  on class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell`  define an event

and where you Updating collection with desired items

```
   Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_upsell', array(
        'product'       => $product,
        'collection'    => $this->_itemCollection,
        'limit'         => $this->getItemLimit()
    ));
```

### config.xml code:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
    <catalog_product_upsellf> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <catalog_product_upsellf_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento58700/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>filtersaleable</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </catalog_product_upsellf_handler>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_upsellf>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

### Observer code is

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento58700_Model_Observer
{
    public function filtersaleable(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe it would be helpful if I didn't find extension iWeb Auto Related Products which has this function in it.